# Extracting tokens from a text file?

Tags: java, text, token

I want to be able to extract text from text files as tokens - for example, say I have a text file that contains the sentence:

It's a good restaurant,

believe me!

I want to extract the contents of this as 'tokens' - for example, one token would be "It's", the next token would be " ", the one after that would be "a", then " ", then "good", then "restaurant", then "," and "\n", then "believe", " ", "me", "!". So I guess one way of putting it is that tokens are either words or not words.

Here is what I have so far (I check to see if the token is a word or not elsewhere in the program, this method just returns the next token):

```
public Token next() {
  if (c == -1) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

  Writer sw=new CharArrayWriter();
  try {
        while ( c != -1 && Character.isLetter(c) ) {
            sw.write(c);
            c = r.read();
        }
        while ( c != -1 && !Character.isLetter(c)) {
            c = r.read();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        c = -1;
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Right now I have the return values as 'null' because I'm not sure how to use the writer to export it as tokens. Does anyone have any tips for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that a solution using Matcher class could solve your issue.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+|\\p{Digit}+|\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Space}+").matcher("It's a good restaurant, believe me!");
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(">"+m.group()+"<");
```

Maybe this regex could not be the right one, but you can build a better one. See the Pattern documentation in:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Regex is indeed a solution, but I think that one will match only strings that consist entirely of one of the character classes you mentionned... You used greedy quantifiers, and one statement, so when it finds a series of alphabetic characters, it satisfies one of the 4 groups and the others will be ignored, even if not the entire string has been matched... I think, I'm no real regex guru...

Comment: The challenge is to define what's part of a word and what's not. The regex above is an example based on different classes of chars. Some chars of punctuation, like apostrophe, can be joined in the alpha chars, solving the problem of separation: "[\\p{Alpha}\\']+|\\p{Digit}+|\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Space}+" Indeed, each pattern must match a entire group of words, numbers, white spaces and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Scanner class it might suit your needs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

If you build a Scanner from your file, you can use the `next()` method to get your tokens.